# ElasticSearch NEST Elastic Client lifetime

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In an ASP.NET application. What would be the advised usage of the ElasticClient: once per application, once per request or just create & destroy when necessary?

What are implications towards caching, warming up, ...?

Is there any part of the documentation that goes into this? I've read a few statements online that cache is per AppDomain, but I would like to find out more details about this area of NEST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client is stateless so whether you register it as a singleton or instantiate a new object functionally should not matter.

The only big **but** to this rule is when you introduce `IConnectionPool` this has some internal state dealing with known nodes and **should** be registered as a singleton.

All the caching bits are per appdomain (static) no matter how you register, instantiate the clients.

Comment: Revisiting an old question here: When using IConnectionPool, is it enough to make the IConnectionPool to be a singleton, or should the ElasticClient be a singleton?